# Bad request response to fetch REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch-api

I have built an API and app that uses that API. When I `POST` method via Postman, it works fine, but when I try fetching it via app, I get a bad request 400 status response. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my JavaScript code:

```js
const myForm = document.getElementById('loginForm');

myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const url = 'https://thawing-peak-69345.herokuapp.com/api/auth';

  const myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append('Accept', 'application/json, text/html, */* ');
  myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json, charset=utf-8')


  const formData = {
    email: this.email.value,
    password: this.password.value
  };


  console.log(formData);

  const fetchOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: JSON.stringify(formData)
  };

  fetch(url, fetchOptions)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))

})
```

**Request**

[image: request photo]

**Response**

[image]

**Headers request**:

[image]

**Headers response**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> ```
> mode: 'no-cors',
> ```

This is a declaration that you are not doing anything that requires permission be granted with CORS. If you try to do anything that does need permission, it will be silently ignored.

> ```
> myHeaders.append( 'Content-Type', 'application/json, charset=utf-8')
> ```

Setting the `Content-Type` header to a value not supported by the HTML `form` element's `type` attribute requires permission from CORS. `application/json` is not such a value.

Consequently, the request is sent as `text/plain`.

Since it isn't marked as being JSON, the server throws a 400 error.

You need to:

- Remove `mode: 'no-cors',`
- Make sure that the service you are making the request to will use CORS to grant you permission (or to use a service on the same origin as the request).

Comment: thatk you for your feedback. I tried before without "no-cors" but then I had Access-Control-Allow-Origin response:(

Comment: @Monika — hence "Make sure that the service you are making the request to will use CORS to grant you permission"